# Using source maps when debugging babel-watch output

Tags: node.js, debugging, babeljs, source-maps, babel-node

Using `babel-watch`, when debugging through the Chrome inspector, I don't have source maps available.

When running the same code using `babel-node`, with the same `.babelrc`, source maps are available.

Here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } } ]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": "inline"
}
```

How do I make source maps available in `babel-watch`?

Comment: Following! I got the same issue, only with a vscode debugger, and a node server app. With babel-node, I see my own version of the code, but it won't restart on changes, and with babel-watch it does restart on changes, but no sourcemaps... so I see an uglified version of my code. I wish there's a way to enjoy both worlds.